# O que faz a prop "jsx" no <style jsx> do Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

No Next.js, podemos inserir a estilização direto no componente através da tag `<style jsx>`, como no exemplo:

```
function Vitro() {
    return (
        <div className="vitro">
            <style jsx>{`
                .vitro {
                    background-color: blue;
                }
            `}</style>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Entretanto, ao remover a propriedade `jsx` de `<style jsx>`, tudo continua a funcionar normal. O que então faz esse atributo?

Comment: Acho que esse artigo pode te ajudar - https://nextjs.org/blog/styling-next-with-styled-jsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto é a sintaxe de uma [biblioteca padrão](https://nextjs.org/blog/styling-next-with-styled-jsx) do NextJS, esta se chama Styled JSX, e o fato de se usar `<style jsx>` é para não se confundir com a própria tag `<style>` do HTML.

O que tem de especial nela é que ela encapsula e mantém o escopo do estilo no seu componente, sem afetar outros componentes, oque permite você alterar/excluir/criar códigos de estilo sem se preocupar com efeitos colaterais.

`<style jsx>` é a tag que indica o inicio do escopo e da estilização. Exemplo:

```js
// pages/index.js
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Hello Next.js</h1>
      <p>Let's explore different ways to style Next.js apps</p>
      <style jsx>{`
        .container {
          margin: 50px;
        }
        p {
          color: blue;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

O código de estilo acima, se aplica somente ao componente `Home()`, ou seja, somente o `<p>` e a `div` de classe `container` serão afetados pelas regras de estilização e mesmo que outros componentes tenham esse elemento `<p>` ou classe `container`, **eles não serão afetados**.

É possível criar estilos globais com essa tag, basta passar o atributo `global`:

```js
// pages/index.js
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Hello Next.js</h1>
      <p>Let's explore different ways to style Next.js apps</p>
      <style jsx global>{`
        .container {
          margin: 50px;
        }
        p {
          color: blue;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Isto aplica estilizações para todos os elementos `p` ou de classe `container` nesta página.

Answer (score 4):

De fato não é a mesma coisa.

Quando você adiciona a *prop* `jsx`, o "compilador" (trata-se de um [*plugin* do Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins)) reconhece que a biblioteca `styled-jsx` deve assumir a "estilização". A partir daí, o *plugin* do Babel realizará as devidas transformações no estilo, que não são feitas com o `<style>` "padrão" do HTML.

Veja esse comportamento no [código-fonte](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/blob/master/src/babel.js#L195) do *plugin* – repare que nada acontece se elementos `<style>` não possuirem a propriedade `jsx`.

Quando a propriedade `jsx` não é fornecida, nada acontece. A tag `<style>` é renderizada normalmente como qualquer outro elemento do DOM. Naturalmente, os estilos são aplicados.

Veja nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor a diferença entre o `<style jsx>` e `<style>` após o "pré-processamento" – nulo neste último caso.